# I have an image from ImageView and then i want to set to PDF, so how to use that?

Tags: android, image, itext, pdf-generation

I am new to Android application development. Using iText I had done the PDF creation and write on that created file now I want to create image to PDF from my `ImageView. Here's my code :

```
public class PdfCreatorActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "PdfCreatorActivity";
    private EditText  mContentEditText;
    private Button mCreateButton;
    private File pdfFile;
    final private int REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS = 111;

    Intent intent;
    Uri fileUri;
    Button btn_choose_image;
    ImageView imageView;
    Bitmap bitmap, decoded;
    public final int REQUEST_CAMERA = 0;
    public final int SELECT_FILE = 1;

    int bitmap_size = 40; // image quality 1 - 100;
    int max_resolution_image = 800;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pdfcreator);

        btn_choose_image = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_choose_image);
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);
        btn_choose_image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                selectImage();
            }
        });

        mContentEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text_content);
        mCreateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_create);
        mCreateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mContentEditText.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
                    mContentEditText.setError("Body is empty");
                    mContentEditText.requestFocus();
                    return;
                }

                try {
                    createPdfWrapper();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (DocumentException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });

    }

    private void selectImage() {
        imageView.setImageResource(0);
        final CharSequence[] items = {"Take Photo", "Choose from Library", "Cancel"};

        android.app.AlertDialog.Builder builder = new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(PdfCreatorActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle("Add Photo!");
        builder.setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                if (items[item].equals("Take Photo")) {
                    intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri();
                    intent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
                } else if (items[item].equals("Choose from Library")) {
                    intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setType("image/*");
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), SELECT_FILE);
                } else if (items[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        Log.e("onActivityResult", "requestCode " + requestCode + ", resultCode " + resultCode);

        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA) {
                try {
                    Log.e("CAMERA", fileUri.getPath());

                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileUri.getPath());
                    setToImageView(getResizedBitmap(bitmap, max_resolution_image));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
                try {
                    // mengambil gambar dari Gallery
                    bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(PdfCreatorActivity.this.getContentResolver(), data.getData());
                    setToImageView(getResizedBitmap(bitmap, max_resolution_image));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Untuk menampilkan bitmap pada ImageView
    private void setToImageView(Bitmap bmp) {
        //compress image
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, bitmap_size, bytes);
        decoded = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes.toByteArray()));

        //menampilkan gambar yang dipilih dari camera/gallery ke ImageView
        imageView.setImageBitmap(decoded);
    }

    // Untuk resize bitmap
    public Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap image, int maxSize) {
        int width = image.getWidth();
        int height = image.getHeight();

        float bitmapRatio = (float) width / (float) height;
        if (bitmapRatio > 1) {
            width = maxSize;
            height = (int) (width / bitmapRatio);
        } else {
            height = maxSize;
            width = (int) (height * bitmapRatio);
        }
        return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, width, height, true);
    }

    public Uri getOutputMediaFileUri() {
        return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile());
    }

    private static File getOutputMediaFile() {

        // External sdcard location
        File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "DeKa");

        // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
        if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
            if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
                Log.e("Monitoring", "Oops! Failed create Monitoring directory");
                return null;
            }
        }

        // Create a media file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
        File mediaFile;
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + "IMG_DeKa_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");

        return mediaFile;
    }
}
```

This Code for Create PDF

```
private void createPdfWrapper() throws FileNotFoundException,DocumentException{

    int hasWriteStoragePermission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    if (hasWriteStoragePermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (!shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS)) {
                showMessageOKCancel("You need to allow access to Storage",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                                    requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                                            REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS);
                                }
                            }
                        });
                return;
            }


            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS);
        }
        return;
    }else {
        createPdf();
    }
}
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS:
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // Permission Granted
                try {
                    createPdfWrapper();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (DocumentException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                // Permission Denied
                Toast.makeText(this, "WRITE_EXTERNAL Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
            break;
        default:
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
}

private void showMessageOKCancel(String message, DialogInterface.OnClickListener okListener) {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setMessage(message)
            .setPositiveButton("OK", okListener)
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
            .create()
            .show();
}

private void createPdf() throws FileNotFoundException, DocumentException {

    File docsFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Documents");
    if (!docsFolder.exists()) {
        docsFolder.mkdir();
        Log.i(TAG, "Created a new directory for PDF");
    }

    pdfFile = new File(docsFolder.getAbsolutePath(),"HelloWorld.pdf");
    OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(pdfFile);
    Document document = new Document();
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, output);
    document.open();
    document.add(new Paragraph(mContentEditText.getText().toString()));

    document.close();
    previewPdf();

}

private void previewPdf() {

    PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
    Intent testIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    testIntent.setType("application/pdf");
    List list = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(testIntent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
    if (list.size() > 0) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(pdfFile);
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");

        startActivity(intent);
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(this,"Download a PDF Viewer to see the generated PDF",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
 }
```

I don't know how to implement image can generates to PDF using iText,
Examples will be appreciable...

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use [PdfDocument](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/pdf/PdfDocument.html) to generate pdf form View.

> This class enables generating a PDF document from native Android content

Sample code:

```
// Create a new document 
PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();
 // crate a page description
PageInfo pageInfo = new PageInfo.Builder(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(), 1).create();
// start a page
 Page page = document.startPage(pageInfo);
 // draw on page 
 view.draw(page.getCanvas());
 // finish the page 
  document.finishPage(page);
 // generate pdf 
 new PdfGenerationTask().execute();
```

Use `AsyncTask` to generate pdf form `document`

```
  private class PdfGenerationTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, File> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected File doInBackground(Void... params) {
        return generatePdf();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(File file) {

        /* Dismiss the progress dialog after sharing */

    }

}
```

`generatePdf` method

```
  private File generatePdf(){


    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyyhhmmss");
    String pdfName = "pdf"
            + sdf.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()) + ".pdf";


    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Pdf";

    File dir = new File(path);
    if(!dir.exists())
        dir.mkdirs();


    File file = new File(dir, pdfName);

    if( document != null ){

        // write the document content
        try {
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);

            if( out != null ){
                document.writeTo(out);
                // close the document
                document.close();
                out.close();
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

 return file;

}
```

[PdfDocument](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/pdf/PdfDocument.html) is easy and simple to use. [PdfDocument](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/pdf/PdfDocument.html) required `min sdk 19`